# Why are 12 bytes being allocated to my struct here?

Tags: c

This is my program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct abc {
    int a;
    char b;
    float c;
};

int main() {
    printf("%d", sizeof(struct abc));
    return 0;
}
```

My system is 64 bit.

I was expecting the result to be 16 assuming word size for my system would be 8 bytes.

Comment: You have to read about structure packing and maybe consider elements reordering if you want to optimize it's memory footprint

Comment: Try outputting `sizeof(int)`. It's probably 4. Also, use `%zu` instead of `%d` as the format specifier because `sizeof` provides a `size_t` value.

Comment: For the `int` and the `float` to be properly aligned, padding may be added between fields or at the end (to ensure correct alignment when you have an array of these structs).

Comment: On most 64-bit systems, `int`s are still only 32 bits.

Comment: Your expectation seems to be based on an assumption that structure sizes must be multiples of the machine word size.  That assumption is not supported by the C language spec, and it is invalid for most C implementations.